# Get the result back from PHP as JSON and parse it using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a `$.post(file.php)` in jquery, directed at "file.php", which sends the result back in a json format using `json_encode()`. Everything is OK and I am getting the result back but I don't know how to separate them. How do I seperate all the data in json format in javascript or jquery?

Comment: Can you show the sample JSON result you are getting?

Comment: If by "separate" you mean "parse", then pass `"json"` as the last argument to `$.post`, and jQuery will parse it for you.

Comment: @amirali Post your PHP code (relevant JSON echo part) so that we can see the way you are generating your JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you send from PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name));
```

You can access these values in JS as:

```
var id = response.id;
var name = response.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

json is a string (serialized) format of an array or object

when you get the result from ajax you can `jQuery.parseJSON( your variable here)`

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(json_variable);
json.a;
```

or
    json.index

or what ever is the index in the original array or object